# Javamail: how to fetch messages modified since a specific date

Tags: jakarta-mail

I'm writing an application that synchronize emails (inbox only) from an IMAP server. For that I'm using javamail and I have performance issue. When I want to refresh my emails, I fetch all messages in inbox, and it takes several minutes. :(
So I would like to fetch only messages that were modified since the last time I refreshed emails. I found how to fetch messages received or sent since a date, but what I want to do is slightly different. It is possible to change the state of a very old message (unread to read). In this case the modification date is recent but received or send date is old.

Any idea ?

Regards,
Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the content of an old message, but you can change the flags.  You can fetch all the flags for all messages and compare them with your cached copy of the flags.  (There are IMAP extensions that help with this, but many IMAP servers don't support them and JavaMail doesn't support them.)

Use the Folder.fetch method to fetch all the flags in one operation, then iterate over the Message objects and compare the flags.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Is the String returned by MimeMessage::getMessageId a uniq identifier that can be used to match local messages and fetched messages ?

Comment: The intent is that it's unique, but nothing guarantees that it's unique so it's not impossible that you'll see a conflict or a message without a Message-ID, although it should be rare.  Note that this is an internet mail issue, not something specific to JavaMail.

Comment: @Quentin I know this is pretty late, but if you need unique identifiers for messages, you could use a combination of folder name + message uid + uid validity (see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#section-2.3.1.1)